# How to use "get late"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I know the meaning and usage of "get late" in "It's getting late, I've got to go"
Now I am wondering if it is correct to use the phrase "get late" in this sentence: "Sorry I got late for school today" or rather "Sorry I got late to school today" or "Sorry I arrived late at school today".Which is correct?
In the same way, is it correct to use it like this: "He is running because he is afraid of getting late for school on the first day (of school)"
Thanks you all.

Answer (score 2):

Sentence: "It's getting late, I've got to go"

That's idiomatic, yes. **The entire phrase refers to time**: it's getting late.
The it is called a dummy pronoun and refers to a time. Dummy pronouns are used a lot in English: "It's odd that you think my letter is good."

However, a person is late. A person does not "get late". A person can get other things though: get rich, get poor, get tired. In this usage the verb get means become.

**I am late for school. It got late.** [it=time expressed with dummy pronoun].

Comment: You seem to have opposite takes on a person getting late. Could you tell me more on this?

Comment: I mean you two!

Answer (score 1):

You can *get to school late*.

And when you're running late, you're afraid of **being late for school** or of **getting to school late**.

Notice the different placement of the word **late**.

We don't say *get late to school*. <sup>not idiomatic</sup> Rather, you get to school late.

But you can "get late *for* school" as the result of some delay.

Comment: You seem to have opposite takes on a person getting late. Could you tell me more on this?

Comment: I mean you two!

Comment: That's because of his last line. He means: It can get late for school. Meaning: It's too late to go to school. So, there is no disagreement. "It's getting late for that."

Comment: Or "late for school" is your state. You  can become late for school if you experience a delay.  There is a roadblock because of an accident, and you can say "Now I am late for school" because "I got delayed". That is not the same as arriving late: *I will get to school late*.